# How to fill a 2d array column by column instead of row by row

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, matrix

I have a of a .txt financial statement that was downloaded from the internet.  When it was downloaded the cells were taken column by column... screwing up my ability to rebuild the statement in a simple manner.

So my question is how to fill a 2d array column by column instead of row by row.  Obviously in a loop you have to skip over the rows, but I am rusty and having trouble figuring this simple problem out. Help por favor.

this is the income statement I am trying to rebuild in 53 rows and 11 columns
[PASTEBUCKET.COM/2303](http://www.pastebucket.com/2303)

and my normal sorting way. Which most likely won't be of great use

```
    String [][] fs = new String[53][11];
    while (input.hasNextLine())
    {   
            for(int row=0;row<53;row++){
                for (int col=0;col<11;col++){
                fs[row][col] = input.nextLine();
                System.out.printf("%s\t",fs[row][col]);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Switch the loops? I think it's really as simple as that

Comment: why do you need it that way? to read it you could simply iterate the other way around, siwtching the loops.

Comment: no one ever reads financial statements top to bottom

Comment: But i tried the reverse loop and it doesn't seem to be clear it it worked.

Comment: It works. Thanks Guys. Once I got it in a JTable it was easy to see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply reverse which for loop runs inside the other.

```
for (int col=0;col<11;col++){
    for (int row=0;row<53;row++){
        fs[row][col] = input.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("%s\t",fs[row][col]);
    }
}
```